# Django Dynamic Navbar Links

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django website where I have two separate user bases, one is CustomUser the other is Agent. Both models extend AbstractUser model. Now I have separate login urls for both and both logins work fine, like Agents can login through AgentSignIn form only and users can login through UserSignIn form only. But now a problem is that when I login as an Agent through AgentSignIn form, I want to show the links Dashboard(agent dashboard) and Agent Sign Out instead of Sign In and Agent Sign In links. But the problem is I don't know how to let my home view know if an Agent is authenticated or a user. Also how do I write the base.html code?

My models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='CustomUser_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='customuser_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')
    is_user = True

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'



class Agent(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agent_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')
    is_agent = True

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'agent_email'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('agent-dashboard', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Agents'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Agent {self.name}'
```

My forms.py:

```
class UserSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This form is for User login only")
        return super().confirm_login_allowed(user)

class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not isinstance(user, Agent):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This form is for Agent login only")
        return super().confirm_login_allowed(user)
```

My backends.py:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

class AgentAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            agent = Agent.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(agent_email=username)) 
        except Agent.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
        if agent.check_password(password):
            return agent
        return None
```

My views.py:

```
class UserLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_backend = "users.backends.UserAuthBackend"
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = UserSignInForm

class AgentLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_backend = "users.backends.AgentAuthBackend"
    template_name = 'users/agent_login.html'
    form_class = AgentSignInForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Before login, request.user:", self.request.user)
        
        agent = form.get_user()
        # Set the authentication backend before login
        agent.backend = self.authentication_backend
        login(self.request, agent)

        print("After login, request.user:", self.request.user)

        return redirect('home')  # Adjust the redirect URL as needed

def home(request):
    agents = Agent.objects.all()
    properties = Property.objects.all()

    # Check if the user is authenticated and an instance of Agent
    is_agent = request.user.is_authenticated and isinstance(request.user, Agent)

    # Print debugging statements
    print(f"User: {request.user}")
    print(f"Is Agent: {is_agent}")

    context = {'agents': agents, 'properties': properties, 'is_agent': is_agent}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

My signals.py:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(user, Agent):
        request.user = user
```

My middleware.py:

```
class AgentAuthenticationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if hasattr(request, 'user') and isinstance(request.user, Agent):
            request.user = request.user
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

My base.html:

```
{% if is_agent %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'agent-dashboard' request.user.agent.slug %}">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-out' %}">Agent Sign Out</a></li>
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

The print statements return:

```
Before login, request.user: AnonymousUser
After login, request.user: Agent Steve Smith
User: AnonymousUser
Is Agent: False
```

Why do you think this is happening and what do I need to do to fix this?